# Caching a package mirror

Tags: cache

I would like to provide a cache for a package mirror. aka you try to pull down a file from the cache node and if it doesn't have it locally, it will pull it down from the mirror and cache it for X amount of time. The intention is for it to work this way as opposed to populating the cache by downloading every file in the mirror.

Is squid do the job and is it the best solution? There doesn't seem to be plentiful docs about squid config out there, so I wonder if people have using something else for file caching.

Answer (score 0):

Squid,I think, is best solution and there is a lot of guides how to setup Squid. You can setup Squid by [this](http://goo.gl/dDOq2D) guide.